# Use powershell/7za.exe to extract multiple zip files?

Tags: powershell, 7zip

The following code

```
ls *.zip | % { c:\bin\7za.exe e $_ -o..\..\unzipped }
ls *.zip | % { c:\bin\7za.exe e $_.name -o..\..\unzipped }
```

got the following error messages. Is it powershell calling exe file convention issue?

```
Error:
Incorrect command line

Error:
Incorrect command line

Error:
Incorrect command line
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following script works.

```
ls *.zip | % { c:\bin\7za.exe e $_ `-o..\..\unzipped }
```

It needs to add a backtick in front of `-o`. Don't know the reason though. Maybe the `-o` will be interpreted as powershell's option instead of the executable's?

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the 7-ZIP command line `7za.exe` tool. To use a relative path as the output directory, wrap it into double quotes as

```
ls *.zip | % { c:\bin\7za.exe e $_.FullName -o"..\..\unzipped" }
```

Note that the path will be relative to the current directory, not the archive or `7za.exe`.